# how do i call a Vf page with parameters from a button in another VF page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am having button on VF page for print of the VF page. 
This page is a search result, so for printing i am generating a very similar page except that it is going to be rendered as pdf. So i want to pass the search criteria entered in the current Vf page to printVF page.

How do i pass variables from one VF page to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the button call an action returning a page reference to the new page:

```
<!-- in page -->
<apex:commandButton action="{!PrintPage}" value="Print"/>
```

And then in your controller you can create the page reference and add any parameters you need to:

```
// in controller
public Pagereference PrintPage()
{
    Pagereference pr = Page.ThePrintPage;
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    pr.getParameters().put('searchFilter1', 'someValue');
    pr.getParameters().put('searchFilter2', 'someOtherValue');
    return pr;
}
```

Then in the controller for the other page you can just read these parameters and use them in your query:

```
string strFilter1 = ApexPgaes.currentPage().getParameters().get('searchFilter1');
```

If the page is very similar, you may just want to switch the `renderAs` parameter in the page tag using a bound variable, and have your action just toggle that — you'd probably want to turn off visibility of other page pieces too, but it would save you doing the query again etc. Of course, if you do need two pages you can always simplify things by doing the search logic in a third class which contains all of the common code.

Comment: The pages are quite similar except that there are 2 tables in the calling Vf page and i want to print 1 table at a time. What do you think would be the best way

Comment: If the print buttons are per table you could still do it that way easily enough, though I'd be inclined to go with two pages to keep things clean in the pages themselves.

Comment: Thinking on what you said, should i call the same page with the parameters passed and hide the unwanted page items and change the render atribute to pdf

Comment: Yep, exactly that. It's down to preference really, this way saves you reloading and filtering the data and a bit of abstraction, but it does add a bit of cruft to the page markup.

Comment: I think i will go with the 2 page scenario as it lessens the complexity of the page